# kubectl on on Powershell gives a string representation of a custom object created from JSON

Tags: powershell, kubectl, output-formatting

I ran into this weird issue and wonder if how to resolve it.

On my Windows machine running Powershell 5.1.19041.1682 (major.minor.build.revision), this command below gives me a proper JSON.

```
PS C:\workspace\rapidresponse\jenkinslib-ds\resources\scripts> kubectl get accountquota account-name-quota -o jsonpath="{.status.total}"

{"hard":{"limits.cpu":"256","limits.memory":"256G","pods":"200","requests.cpu":"64","requests.memory":"128G"},"used":{"limits.cpu":"28","limits.memory":"73Gi","pods":"13","requests.cpu":"28","requests.memory":"73Gi"}}
```

**Edit:** The kubectl version here is `1.24.1`

However, on another machine (a Windows machine as well running an older version 5.1.14393.2636), I got a completely different result.

```
PS C:\Users\sa_a9_dst_validation> kubectl get accountquota account-name-quota -o jsonpath="{.status.total}"

map[hard:map[limits.cpu:256 limits.memory:256G pods:200 requests.cpu:64 requests.memory:128G] used:map[limits.cpu:27 lim
its.memory:72Gi pods:12 requests.cpu:27 requests.memory:72Gi]]
```

**Edit:** The version of kubectl of this machine is `1.18.2`

The result looks like the JSON is internally converted into a PS Custom Object and ​`ToString()​` is called on it before the result is returned.

**My goal**

I am trying to convert the JSON result into an object, i.e. using `ConvertFrom-Json`. Having a strange string like that forces me to write a custom parser for it and it is not what I want to do. Do you know of a reason for why it behaves that way? If so, is there a way to use existing Powershell functions to do so?

Comment: What version of kubectl are you using on each machine? (```kubectl version``` or ```kubectl version --short```)

Comment: @mclayton I edited my post to add the version information. It is 1.24.1 vs 1.18.2.

Comment: That certainly _does not_ look like JSON "converted into a PS Custom Object and ​ToString()​ is called on it before the result is returned." :)

Comment: PowerShell is indeed incidental to your problem (aside from decoding stdout output into _strings_, no transformation is attempted on output from external programs). I suggest either upgrading your older `kubectl` version or - I'm guessing - perhaps adding `-o json` as well helps.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that is my guess given that the resulting string displays 2 separate internal maps/hashtables.

Comment: @PhuongHoang yeah, but string formatting in PowerShell 5.1 would result in a string like `@{hard=@{...}}`

Comment: The output format - undoubtedly created by `kubectrl` itself, not PowerShell - looks like a stringified golang map.

Comment: Ah, that explains. I will update `kubectl` and see if it resolves my issue.

Comment: This page (and a couple of others I found) - https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_get/ - suggests the syntax is ```-o=jsonpath=<template>``` whereas the official docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/#syntax-1 - say it's ```-o jsonpath=<template>```. I'm speculating wildly, but maybe it was a breaking change between versions?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `kubectl` version `1.18.2` is indeed the one that causes the issue. When I downgraded my `kubectl` version from `1.24.2` to `1.18.2`, I could reproduce the issue.

Thanks @@mclayton, @MathiasR.Jessen, and @mklement0

Comment: For version 1.18.2, have you tried the alternate syntax I found - ```-o=jsonpath=<template>```? It’s not on the official site, but that might be because it’s changed in newer versions. Or might just be garbage :-)…

Comment: @mclayton I have tried that and it produced the same result as `-o jsonpath=<template>`.